# Set background image as a link?

Tags: hyperlink, background

I have a .big-container (`width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden;`) and in this a .container (`width: 982px; height: 100%; overflow: hidden;`).

I'd like to set it up so that when somebody clicks the .big-container (background) where there is no content (.content), to drop fx. www.google.hu

Here is the picture: (Gray parts to click)

[image]

How to do that? (Maybe with jQuery).

Answer (score 2):

with jQuery..

```
$(".big-contaner").click(function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
  // do something
});
```

you need event.stopPropagation() for custom (different from .big-container) click event managment inside child elements such as .content etc

Comment: http://dockyardlan.com/ Please check. When I click on a space on the .container whick is free (so there is no any image, text), it drops me too. Problem? :S ($('.big-container').click(function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
  location.href = 'http://alienware.hu';
 }); )

Comment: I've tried to reproduce it with FF 9.0 but I get redirected only by clicking on gray areas. What browser do you use?

Comment: Tried with much. Resolution: $('.big-container').click( function (event) {
  if (event.target == this) {
   window.open('http://alienware.hu', '_blank');
  }
 });

Comment: Sorry, my English is too bad. Did you manage to get it working with your code above? If you did I hope that somehow my answer was helpful for you.